# Why the error rates in table3 and table4 are differenct in the paper "deep residual learning for image recognition"

Tags: deep-learning

Why are the error rates in table 3 and table 4 are different in the paper [Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition (2015)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf).

They are both error rates on the validation sets by single model.

- Why there are different rates for the same architecture?